# Is there (or will there be) an image spriting syntax in HTML?

Tags: html, css, background-image, image

I'm not up to date on the latest CSS improvements, so I figured it was worth asking;

An `<img>` element is nicely written as `<img src="/url.png" />`, with the height and width auto or specified. I like CSS sprites for their obvious loading speed advantage, yet hate writing out all that CSS for it. Is there, or will there ever be, a syntax like `<img src="/url.png" Xpx Ypx />`, where X/Y represent a location shift similar to CSS's `background-position`?

I understand that it would be wonky with regards to image dimensions, as they scale in HTML (as opposed to cropping, like a div with a background image would).

Is this possible, or am I just being lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t anything in HTML like that at the moment.

You could use inline CSS on the image tag, if you’ve got a 1-pixel transparent gif or png handy:

```
<img style="background: url(/url.png) -Xpx -Ypx;" src="/1pix.gif" />
```

But you’ll need to set the width and height of the image element so that the sprite background is visible.

You could avoid the need for a transparent image file by including it directly in the `<img>` tag as a data URL:

#### 8-bit PNG

```
<img style="background: url(/url.png) -Xpx -Ypx;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN%2BAAAAAXRS%0ATlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCB1jYAAAAAIAAc/INeUAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D%0A">
```

#### GIF (smaller)

```
<img style="background: url(/url.png) -Xpx -Ypx;" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D%0A">
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/r727j/1/)

But obviously we’re getting into fairly ugly territory here. (And I couldn’t swear that the data URL will work in IE 6.)

Comment: the data url seems wrong, if someone is looking for one: data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==

Comment: @WebDev: ooh dear, you’re quite right — not sure what data URL I put in there, but it didn’t work at all. I’ve corrected the answer, thank you. One note: your data URL appears to be for a *white* 1-pixel GIF, rather than a transparent one — see http://jsfiddle.net/r727j/2/

Comment: haha ok, shame on me, first i wanted to create one, but then stumbled upon this in the jquery masonry plugin ..

Answer (score 4):

Can't imagine that ever coming to pass, and even if it did you'd have the usual cross-browser issues for years. There are numerous services that can work out the CSS/coordinates for you - e.g. [SpriteCow](http://www.spritecow.com).

Comment: I use SpriteCow almost daily. <3

Answer (score -1):

The sprite itself is generally used to combine many small images into one large image. This is done not only save precious loading time and bandwidth, but also to keep your site structure clean and manageable.

example

```
{background-position:0px -143px;} /* what ever*/
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an answer to the OP's question.